# Google Analytics Ecommerce Metrics Showing All Zeros

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, python-3.9

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO:**

I'm trying to query the Google Analytics Core Reporting API v4 using service account credentials for the following dimensions and metrics (FYI I'm aware that you can only include 7 dimensions per call, I'm just listing all that I ultimately want to use because my issue relates to the METRICS and is consistent no matter which combination of dimensions I include in the call):

```
*Dimensions*
ga:transactionId
ga:sessionsToTransaction
ga:daysToTransaction
ga:sessionDurationBucket
ga:referralPath
ga:campaign
ga:source
ga:medium
ga:keyword
ga:socialNetwork
ga:pagePath
ga:landingPagePath
ga:pageDepth

*Metrics*
ga:quantityAddedToCart
ga:quantityCheckedOut
ga:pageviews
ga:avgTimeOnPage
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR:**

While my ultimate goal is to use Python 3.9 to automate the API calls, as a first step I've been testing my queries using the [GA Query Explorer here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/). I've tested multiple GA "View IDs" (my account has access to a half dozen "properties") and I've also tried varying the time period involved to eliminate any issues related to those particulars. Still, the same problem persists. I've also logged directly into the Google Analytics dashboard, and it shows visualizations that appear to be built on some of the same dimensions and metrics.

**THE RESULTS I'VE BEEN GETTING:**

While my query runs, all four of my metrics show zeros in the resulting TSV file. This isn't just a few rows of zeros, the entire columns for the four metrics (ga:quantityAddedToCart, ga:quantityCheckedOut, ga:pageviews, ga:avgTimeOnPage) are only zero values.

Here's a snapshot of the first few rows of data with the transactionId and other sensitive identifiable information redacted:

[image: TSV OUTPUT FROM GA QUERY EXPLORER]

I've also confirmed that "Enable Ecommerce" and "Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting" are set to on, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Any help in understanding why this data would be blank is appreciated. I found [this documentation about the Ecommerce.js plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce), but because I can see related data in the Google Analytics Dashboard it doesn't feel like that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks in part to Michele Pisani's tip about adding/removing dimensions and metrics to tests functional combinations, and despite the GA Query Explorer showing that my specific list of dimensions and metrics should work together, Google Analytics is suppressing certain results by listing them as all zero values whenever the ga:transactionId dimension is included in the query.

This is frustrating since the ga:quantityAddedToCart, ga:quantityCheckedOut, ga:pageviews, and ga:avgTimeOnPage metrics ARE NOT personally identifiable information (like the demographics dimensions/metrics are). So, long story short, GA won't allow me to do what I was hoping to through the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **remove** `ga:sessionDurationBucket` from *dimensions* and **set** `ga:sessionDuration` as *metric*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MichelePisani, however, that didn't work. I'm still getting all zeros for the four original metrics in my query ...

Comment: Is Enhanced Ecommerce configured?

Comment: Yes. I logged into GA and navigated to Admin>Ecommerce Settings, and confirmed that both "Enable Ecommerce" and "Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting" are set to on (I've added this screenshot to my original question).

Comment: Remove some dimensions and metrics from request to understand which of those resets the values. In this way it is possible to investigate the cause.

Comment: Thank you for the additional suggestion. I'm getting some results now, but they're inconsistent and three distinct groups of single dimension/four metric combos are showing up now. "ga:transactionId,ga:sessionsToTransaction,ga:daysToTransaction" always produce zero values for the four metrics.
"ga:sessionDurationBucket,ga:referralPath,ga:campaign,ga:source,ga:medium,ga:keyword,ga:socialNetwork,ga:landingPagePath,ga:pageDepth" produce non-zero data, but it's spotty for some metrics and complete for others. ...

Comment: ... "ga:pagePath" produced non-zero data for three of the metrics (ga:quantityAddedToCart,ga:quantityCheckedOut,ga:pageviews) but was still all zeros for (ga:avgTimeOnPage). What do you believe is behind this inconsistency? It is Google suppressing results that could be associated with a transactionID and/or individual? Or do you suspect something is not set up correctly within GA? Or is there something else entirely that I'm not paying attention to?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any data under Conversions -> Ecommerce -> Transactions report in Google Analytics UI?

Comment: "Transaction Report" isn't an option under my Conversions > Ecommerce. Instead, I have the following: Overview, Shopping Behavior, Checkout Behavior, Product Performance, Sales Performance, Product List Performance and Marketing (which itself has Internal Promotion, Order Coupon, Product Coupon, and Affiliate Code embedded underneath it).